# Javascript function not firing in onchange event

Tags: javascript, c#, grid

I want to get textbox value within gridview using javascript and compare with the 2nd grid cell value.But Javascript function isn't working. How can i do this?
C# code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Received Qty">
 <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" Width="20%" />
     <ItemStyle CssClass="TableCellStyle" />
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtrcvQuantity" runat="server"  onchange="VallidRcvQuantity(this.value)" CssClass="form-control formcontroloverride"></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

  function VallidRcvQuantity() {
      var gridViewCtlId = '<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>';
      var grid = document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId);
      var txtcurrentrcvamount = document.getElementById(txtrcvQuantity).value;
      var cell = grid.rows[0].cells[2].textcontent;
      if (txtcurrentrcvamount > cell ) {
          alert("Receive quantity must be less or equal PO quantity");
          return false;
      }
      return true;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function VallidRcvQuantity() prototype and calling signature are different . When you call the function , you pass an argument 'this.value' but in function definition the signature is entirely different and have void argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calculation() {
  var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvGoodReceived.ClientID%>");
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
    var txtcurrentrcvamount = $("input[id*=txtrcvQuantity]")

    var cell = $("#GridView1").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td:eq(2)").text();
  }
  if (txtcurrentrcvamount > cell) {
    alert("Receive quantity must be less or equal PO quantity");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not  working for my condition. if (txtcurrentrcvamount > cell) . messege is showing always.How can i resolve this?